# What do I add to this code to include additional CPTs?

Tags: conditional-tags

I use the code below to add a message on the edit screen for a CPT 'item'.

```
$screen = get_current_screen();
if($screen->post_type=='item' && $screen->id=='item')
```

What do I need to add to include other CPTs - example 'foo'?

I can do it with 'elseif' but think there's maybe a shorter way by using || with a single 'if'.

Answer (score 0):

To nest a conditional OR wrap conditions with `()` and separate with `||`.

```
if( ($screen->post_type=='item' || $screen->post_type=='product') && $screen->id=='item')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the message on CPT listing page then below is the complete code:

```
function pn_current_screen_example( $current_screen ) {
    if ( ( 'post' === $current_screen->post_type || 'product' === $current_screen->post_type ) && 'edit' == $current_screen->base ) {
        add_action( 'admin_notices', 'pn_sample_admin_notice' );
    }
}
add_action( 'current_screen', 'pn_current_screen_example' );

function pn_sample_admin_notice() {
    ?>
    <div class="notice notice-success is-dismissible">
        <p><?php _e( 'This is sample admin notice!', 'sample-text-domain' ); ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

If you want to show the message on CPT edit page then below is the complete code:

```
function pn_current_screen_example( $current_screen ) {
    if ( ( 'post' === $current_screen->post_type || 'product' === $current_screen->post_type ) && $_GET['action']=== 'edit' ) {
        add_action( 'admin_notices', 'pn_sample_admin_notice' );
    }
}
add_action( 'current_screen', 'pn_current_screen_example' );

function pn_sample_admin_notice() {
    ?>
    <div class="notice notice-success is-dismissible">
        <p><?php _e( 'This is sample admin notice!', 'sample-text-domain' ); ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `in_array` like that :

```
if (    in_array($screen->post_type, ['item', 'product'])
    &&  ($screen->id === $screen->post_type)
) {
    // ...

}
```